# Missing Operating System on USB drive

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, ubuntu-minimal

I'm trying to install the minimal Ubuntu installation on a USB drive (complete install, not a live boot).  After installation, however, when I try to boot from the USB, I get "Missing operating system".

I think there might be a problem with `grub`, but I don't know how to fix it.  I've done an install to an USB before which messed up the main `grub` file, so I don't want to do that.

This is the output of `fdisk -l` pertaining to the USB drive:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 4027 MB, 4027580416 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1023 cylinders, total 7866368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x73a571aa

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048     7616511     3807232   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2         7618558     7864319      122881    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5         7618560     7864319      122880   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Also, my boot partition may not be labeled as bootable, based on this output.  Please help!

### Update

I followed `Terrance`'s suggestion, so /dev/sdc1 is now labeled as a boot partition.  However, the drive still won't boot.

I am not asking for how to install Ubuntu to a USB drive, I'm asking for help fixing a USB which I've already installed Ubuntu to.

### Update

`Terrance`'s updated answer solved it for me.  Just a note, to get it working on my USB I had to create a `/boot/extlinux/syslinux.cfg` file containing:

```
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 50
DEFAULT arch

LABEL arch
        LINUX ../vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
        APPEND root=UUID=[The USB UUID]
        INITRD ../initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install Ubuntu?

Comment: On the contrary: you've installed Ubuntu without any boot files...  Easier to restart the installation like above.

Comment: In the installer I selected the grub installer.  Performing an `ls boot` in the USB drive gives `abi-4.4.0-45-generic     initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
config-4.4.0-45-generic  System.map-4.4.0-45-generic
grub                     vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic`

Comment: @jpyams I updated my answer a bit to hopefully help install the extlinux boot files as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the boot flag on the first partition of your USB drive by typing in the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc set 1 boot on
```

Also try installing `extlinux` and the `syslinux-common` for putting the boot files on the USB drive.  From the terminal, type in:

```
sudo apt install extlinux syslinux-common
```

After those are installed, have your USB drive in and type in:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/USB/boot/extlinux
sudo extlinux --install /mnt/USB/boot/extlinux
```

or whatever the mount point is to your USB drive like `/media/username/1001-BAAB/boot/extlinux`

Then you should install the `mbr` code to the USB drive with the following command:  *Don't worry, this will not overwrite the USB drive.*

```
dd if=/usr/lib/EXTLINUX/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdc bs=440 count=1
```

Make sure that `/dev/sdc` is your USB drive.

More info can be found here:  http://shallowsky.com/linux/extlinux.html

From the manpage for extlinux:

```
NAME
       extlinux  -  install  the SYSLINUX bootloader on a ext2/ext3/ext4/btrfs
       filesystem
```

Hope this helps!